# cannot use a scalar value as an array warning

Tags: php, mysql

```
function update_user_voted($array,$userid=NULL)
{
    global $db;
    //$voted = array();
    if(!$userid)
        $userid = userid();
    if(phpversion < '5.2.0')
    {
        global $json;
        $js = $json;    
    }
    if(is_array($array))
    {
        $votedDetails = $db->select(tbl("users"),"voted"," userid = '$userid'");
        if(!empty($votedDetails))
            if(!empty($js))
                $voted = $js->json_decode($votedDetails[0]['voted'],TRUE);
            else
                $voted = json_decode($votedDetails[0]['voted'],TRUE);

        //$votedArray = $voted;
        $voted[] = $array;

        if(!empty($js))
            $votedEncode = $js->json_encode($voted);
        else
            $votedEncode = json_encode($voted);

        if(!empty($votedEncode))
            $db->update(tbl("users"),array("voted"),array("|no_mc|$votedEncode")," userid='$userid'");      
    }
}
```

When I use this funciton, it perfectly works but it just shows this error:

> **Warning:** Cannot use a scalar value as an array in **/mydirectory/thisfilecontainingthiscode.php** on line **5160** (which is `$voted[] = $array;`).

- Apache version  2.2.27
- PHP version 5.3.28
- MySQL version   5.5.34-cll-lve
- Architecture    x86_64
- Operating system    linux

Saying also that this error is new, I've never had problems with this function. It is used in clip-bucket script.

Comment: `var_dump($voted);` before the line, is it really an array?

Comment: Your `$voted` variable isn't an array, if I had to guess I'd say it's NULL because your JSON is invalid, try checking `json_last_error()` to see what the error code was. http://php.net/json_last_error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare **$voted** as array before increasing the index. You are trying to push a new element to the array with a complex structure (could be a scalar value as well), if the json data returns a scalar, you should not be able to push using **$voted[]**.

**$voted = array();**

Comment: $voted comes from one of the lines above it, making it an empty array after that would lose data. Also use `\`` to make code type, or indent lines with four spaces.